# jQuery How to slideUp with delay?

Tags: jquery, delay, slideup

I am using the following jQuery. A div box slides up, and then after 5 seconds, fades out. Is there a way to achieve this as it takes a long time for the box to appear.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#load_limit").slideUp(500); //have tried "fast" also
  $("#load_limit").delay(5000);
  $("#load_limit").slideDown(500);
});
```

Comment: Are you wanting the delay to be shorter?

Comment: @TheBlackBenzKid: The code you posted should work fine. What problems are you having?

Comment: What's wrong with your code? Is it that the div takes a long time to appear and the jQuery is firing off before it loads?

Comment: @AndrewWhitaker It takes a very long time for the box to appear. http://tiny.cc/8x7y1

Comment: No, I want it to appear quickly.. delay for 5seconds... then disappear quickly..

Comment: Can you provide a working example on jsfiddle.com?  This should not take a long time, it should take half a second.

Comment: @JamesMontagne posted a link 4th comment.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can delay in the callback function:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#load_limit").slideUp(500, function() {
     $("#load_limit").delay(5000).slideDown(500);
  }); 
});
```

or you can just simplified it:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#load_limit").slideUp(500)
                  .delay(5000)
                  .slideDown(500);
});
```

Code: http://jsfiddle.net/xjEy5/2/

Comment: There is no reason to do either of those.  `delay` will wait for `slideUp` to complete.  Adding an extra 500 ms will delay an extra 500 ms.

Answer (score 3):

Find the div, wait for n seconds and then take n milliseconds transition time to slide up.

```
$("#div").delay(5000).slideUp(1000);
```

Answer (score 0):

What exactly is wrong with the code you have above? It looks functional (other than you have slideDown/slideUp and no fadeOut as you indicated in the instructions)

Here's an alternative way to achieve the same effect:

```
jQuery(function($) { // same as $(document).ready() but no conflicts :)

   $('#load_limit').slideDown(500, function() {
      var self = this;
      setTimeout(function() {
         $(self).fadeOut(500);
      }, 5000);
   });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Reduce the time in your `.slideUp()` to whatever you need. Here is an example:

`$("#load_limit").slideUp(50).delay(5000).slideDown(50);`

At 50ms you don't really see the `.slideUp()` effect if your content's height is small. That's why it's better to use `.hide()` instead.

Comment: How would I use hide -> example please?