# Slide-down menu after hover, not click

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a problem with getting the menu slide down after hovering. When I move cursor away from the top navigation the menu slides back up. Also, I'd like to add a delay before the menu slides up after moving cursor away from the slided part (let's say 500ms). I tried to find an existing question here and couldn't find the full answer to my question. Here is what I have so far:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var $tabs = $('.menu');

  $('.rozw', $tabs).hide();
  $('.option', $tabs)

    .hover(function() {

      if ($(this).siblings('.rozw').is(':visible')) {
        $(this).siblings('.rozw').slideUp(200);
      } else {
        $('.rozw', $tabs).slideUp(200);
        $(this).siblings('.rozw').slideDown(200, function() {});
      }

    });
});
```

```css
.menu .option {
  background: #FAD9D9;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.menu .rozw {
  background: #DDFAD9;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 5px;
  float: left;
  width: -moz-calc(100% - 10px);
  width: -webkit-calc(100% - 10px);
  width: calc(100% - 10px);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="menu">
  <h3 class="option">Menu</h3>

  <div class="rozw">
    <div class="item">
      <img src="https://cdn3.iconfinder.com/data/icons/diagram_v2/PNG/96x96/diagram_v2-12.png">
      <p>Option</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[JSfiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/tucado/cgm561us/8/)

Thanks

Comment: There are plenty of tutorials and codepen examples. did you try google? why do you even need javascript for that?

Comment: Hi, I tried to find it but there are all different that what I need. Here is the effect I want to achieve: https://www.avehire.co.uk/ (when you highlight the EQUIPMENT HIRE). I also want to apply a delay to slideup after moving coursor away from the actual submenu - so when I accidentally move cursor away for, let's say, 1 second it won't slide up if I manage to hover it again.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jQuery How to slideUp with delay?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9197096/jquery-how-to-slideup-with-delay)

Comment: Or simply using `setTimeout`. Also you can put the dropdown menu inside the menu header itself. That way when moving mouse away from the header and over to the dropdown menu, it won't collapse. Inspect `avehire` closely and you can find all your answer there.

Comment: 2nd hint: avehire adds eventlisteners on both the menu header and on the dropdown menu. Also it uses CSS transition not JS.

Answer (score 0):

Use jquery like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var $tabs = $('.menu');

    $('.rozw', $tabs).hide();
    $('.option').hover(function () {
        $('.rozw').show();
    }, function () {
        $('.rozw').hide();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use CSS with this

```
.menu .option {
 background: #FAD9D9;
 margin: 0px;
 padding: 10px;
 cursor: pointer;
}

.menu .rozw {
 background: #DDFAD9;
 margin: 0px;
 padding: 5px;
 float: left;
 width: -moz-calc(100% - 10px);
 width: -webkit-calc(100% - 10px);
 width: calc(100% - 10px);
 display: none;
}

.menu:hover .rozw {
  display: block;
}
```

Comment: thanks, but unfortunately it slides back up when I move cursor away from the actual .option div. I want it to stay slided down until I move the cursor away from the .rozw div for more than 500ms.

Comment: you can use this method, this is only CSS without JS